# Docker containers in user defined docker network - access only from the host

Tags: docker, docker-network

I have an application that is creating a few containers in a **user-defined docker network**.

Currently I have **forwarded (mapped) few ports** from some of the containers in that network to the **host machine** so that I can access them from the **host**. The interaction between the containers (container to container) is happening via **aliases** that are defined in the network.

Unfortunately the **map ports** to the host are **publicly exposed** on my host machine. Is there a way that these mapped ports can be accessible only from the **localhost** of my host machine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using docker run -p [port-number]:[port-number] to forward your ports, you can use:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:80:80 container
```

instead of:

```
docker run -p 80:80 container
```

By default, Docker exposes your ports on all available interfaces.

Comment: I think this is what I need and what I missed from the docker documentation. I just found it here https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/ (row 2) after reading your comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are on linux you can use iptables for that.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s localhost --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DROP
```

Just change `8080` for the port you want and run it multiple times for each port you are exposing.

First command is "anything coming from localhost to port 8080 allow it" and second is "drop anything coming into port 8080"

This change is not permanent it will reset after you reboot, but you can save it with:

```
iptables-save > /etc/iptables.conf
```

And restore it with:

```
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.conf
```